# Host excel file in wpf application

Tags: wpf

I am having one excel file that i need to host or embed in wpf application. that file need to open inside wpf application.. and user can do modification into that. 
is there any solution for this....

Thanks 
Brijesh

Comment: A Google search for "read update excel wpf" showed up several promising sites - both for existing components and do-it-yourself approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for hosting microsoft excel in my WPF application. Searching on internet for some time , i got below answer.

[hosting stand alone office in WPF application](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/vswpfdesigner/thread/e70358e7-919a-44a4-8b45-73f7ee4f9db4)